# everthing is fine but firestore isn't getting imported nor data get stored in firestore and in below picture you can see the errors of unknown words

Tags: html, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[firestore isn't working don't know y? i am using 11.9.0 version of firebase
and secondly didn,t get the point of showing these error of unknown words](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEVsh.png)

Comment: The community will be able to help answer better if you copy/paste/format as text instead of as an image! Check out this post for more details: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.